# Ruby craziness: Class vs Object?

Tags: ruby, class, object

I just started playing with JRuby. This is my first ruby post. I had a hard time understanding classes vs objects in Ruby. It doesnt mean like what classes & objects in other Object oriented laguages. for an example

```
Class.is_a? Object
```

returns **true**
and

```
Object.is_a? Object
```

**too**.

so class & Object are both objects

here comes another one

```
Class.is_a? Class
```

returns **true**
and

```
Object.is_a? Class
```

**too**.

wait, i am not done yet

```
 Object.instance_of? Class
 Class.instance_of? Class
```

Both are true

```
 Object.instance_of? Object
 Class.instance_of? Object
```

Both are false. right, nothing can be instance of object.

And

```
 Class.kind_of? Class
 Object.kind_of? Class
```

both are true

```
 Class.kind_of? Object
 Object.kind_of? Object
```

both are true

So both are exactly same, then why do we have both these.?

After some more digging, i wrote this simple method to return method list supported by both

```
irb(main):054:0> def print_methods(obj)
irb(main):055:1>    obj.methods.each do |mm|
irb(main):056:2*        puts mm
irb(main):057:2>    end
irb(main):058:1> end
```

Only method difference between print_methods(Object) and print_methods(Class) is

```
     Nesting
```

if Nesting means inheritance, Is Object similar to the sealed class??

Can someone clarify me what is all this?

**Update:** To Edds comment

Interestingly i see lot of differences in the method list in

```
c=Class.new
print_methods(c)
```

&

```
o=Object.new
print_methods(o)
```

Now I understand Instance of a class is really an class instance (And this class instance is actually a Object) not an  object instance. And even this instance allow me to span another instances

```
  xx = c.new //works - c is an Object / and xx is a instance of an Object c
  yy = o.new //nope  - o is already a instance of an Object, so it cannot be instantiated again
```

So Finally, Object is really an instance of a Class. Because

```
  xx.is_a? Class
```

is false, but

```
  xx.is_a? Object
```

returns true

Am i right, ??

Comment: +1: for good deductive skills

Comment: I can heartily recommend the pickaxe treatment of this topic: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/classes.html

Comment: It's also worth noting that your digging so far has looked at class methods of Object and Class, which are similar but not at the instance methods. An instance of Class has a bunch of methods that an instance of Object doesn't have.

If you come across a succinct explanation it would be very interesting to hear it!

Comment: @Edd, i have updated my post, please check out..

Comment: To finde out the difference in methods it's easier to use something like 
 Class.methods - Object.methods .

Comment: "So Finally, Object is really an instance of a Class." - Yes. `Object` in ruby is analogous to `java.lang.Object.class` in Java.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Basically the key thing to understand is that every class is an instance of the `Class` class and every class is a subclass of `Object` (in 1.8 - in 1.9 every class is a subclass of `BasicObject`). So every class is an object in the sense that it is an instance of a subclass of `Object`, i.e. `Class`.

Of course this means that `Class` is an instance of itself. If that makes your brain hurt, just don't think about it too deeply.

#### `Object` and `Class` are `is_a? Object`

`x.is_a? y` returns `true` if `x.class == y or x.class < y`, i.e. if `x`'s class is `y` or `x`'s class inherits from `y`. Since every class inherits from object `x.is_a? Object` returns true no matter what `x` is. (In 1.8 anyway, in 1.9 there's also `BasicObject` which is now the most basic class in the inheritance hierarchy).

#### They are also `is_a? Class`

Both `Object` and `Class` are indeed classes, so that should not be surprising.

#### They are also `instance_of? Class`, but not `instance_of? Object`.

Unlike `is_a?`, `x.instance_of? y` only returns true if `x.class == y`, not if `x.class` is a subclass of `y`. So since both `x` and `y` are `instance_of? Class`, they're not `instance_of? Object`.

> right, nothing can be instance of object.

That's not true. `Object.new.instance_of? Object` is true.

#### kind_of?

`kind_of?` is an alias for `is_a?`, so see above.

> So both are exactly same, then why do we have both these.?

It should be pointed out that everything up to now is true for all classes. E.g. `String.is_a? Object`, `String.is_a? Class` and `String.instance_of? Class` are true and `String.instance_of? Object` is false for the same reasons as above. (Also `String.is_a? String` and `String.instance_of? String` are both false for the same reasons - String is a class, not a string).

You can not conclude from this that all the classes are the same. They're just all instances of the same class.

#### Comparing methods

Since both `Object` and `Class` are classes, they both have all the instance methods defined by `Class`. `Class` additionally has the singleton method `nesting`. `nesting` tells you which module you're currently nested in, it has nothing to do with inheritance.

For any given class `TheClass.methods` will return the instance methods defined by `Class` (e.g. `superclass`, which returns the class which `TheClass` inherits from, and `new` which creates a new instance of `TheClass`) plus the singleton methods defined by that class.

Anyway `methods` only tells you which methods can be called directly on a given object. It does not tell you which methods can be called on an instance of a class. For that you can use `instance_methods`, which returns significantly different results for `Object` and `Class`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation.... I started JRuby just a week, and already in deep love....

Answer (score 19):

In Ruby, everything is an `Object` including classes and modules. `Object` is the most low-level class (well, in Ruby 1.9.2 there is also `BasicObject` but this is an other story).

See the following output.

```
> Object.ancestors
# => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
> Class.ancestors
# => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
> Module.ancestors
# => [Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
> String.ancestors
# => [String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

As you can see, both `Class` and `Module` inherits from `Object`.

Back to your original assertions, you have to understand the difference bewteen

- `is_a?`
- `kind_of'`
- `instance_of?`

They are not interchangeable. `is_a?` and `kind_of?` returns true if other is the same class or an ancestor. Conversely, `instance_of?` returns true only if other is the same class.

```
> Class.is_a? Object
# => true 
> Class.kind_of? Object
# => true 
> Class.instance_of? Object
# => false
```

Comment: this is definitely better than my answer :)

Comment: Which is a good answer, but doesn't entirely explain why `Object.instance_of? Class` is true. I think it's because `Object` is the constant class definition of object, and `Class` is the constant class definition of class, so both are instances of `Class`. It's still not quite clear to me.

Comment: Thanks :) Each on their own makes perfect sense, despite them being a bit surprising in combination. +1.

Answer (score 4):

One of the answers mentions this:

> Basically the key thing to understand is that every class is an
>   instance of the Class class and every class is a subclass of Object.
>   So every class is an object in the sense that it is an instance of a
>   subclass of Object, i.e. Class.

I just want to word it differently for those who have a little brain twist. First ask yourself: What is an instance in programming? And what is a subclass in programming? An instance is just a realized variation of a blueprint (the Class). A subclass is simply a class (blueprint) that inherits from another class (blueprint). So when you create a new class:

```
class Apple
end
```

Apple is an instance of Class, that is, it is a realized variation of the blueprint. It takes the blueprint and fills in the details (methods and variables) with its own variation. Well, the blueprint inherits from another blueprint, which is Object. So every class is an instance of Class, which is a subclass of Object.

```
class A 
end
A.superclass  
=> Object     
A.class  
=> Class
```

Note Class has Module in its inheritance chain (Module included in Class as a mixin perhaps since Class's parent is Object?).

```
A.is_a?(Module)
 => true
```

Instances (A.new) of class A will have their own realized variations of A. But they are object instances. So we must distinguish class instances (e.g. class A end) and object instances ( a = A.new). Object instances have a different inheritance chain. They are a realized variation of a class instance blueprint, not a variation of class Class.

This means in their inheritance chain is not Class or Module. But rather other object instances, so if A has object instances and B has object instances and A inherits from B, when we instantiate a new object instance of A, this instance will have B instances in its inheritance chain.

They will also inherit from Object, since everything in Ruby inherits from Object.

```
a = A.new
 => #<A:0x007f966449b8d8> 
a.is_a?(Class)
 => false 
a.is_a?(Module)
 => false 
a.is_a?(Object)
 => true
```

And this is the best way to think about it all. Do not go too deep with your thinking. Accept this as I have written it.

Answer (score 2):

Ramesh, in ruby **everything** is an object, and a Class is no exception.

try this in irb

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > o = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x000001020114b0> 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > o.is_a? Class
=> false 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > o.is_a? Object
=> true
```

in this case, I've created an instance of an Object, and checked if it's a class (false) or a Object (true).

A Class in ruby, is some kind of template object used to create instances of that class. Sorry that this is not super clear. The key concept is that ruby is a pure object oriented language, as opposed to Java.

Answer (score 2):

The class/metaclass hierarchy is always a little puzzling :) Just for comparison, [here's the one in Smalltalk](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f9/Smalltalk_80_metaclasses.svg); in Ruby, the setup is based on the same principles, except it doesn't have the `Behavior` and `ClassDescription` distinctions, and there are modules and eigenclasses to take into account.

A full explanation of the Smalltalk object model is available in [Pharo by Example](http://pharobyexample.org/), as pointed by this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130161/smalltalk-superclass-vs-metaclass).

Answer (score 1):

As _why writes in [this article](http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html)

> objects do not store methods, only classes can.

The first couple sections have some good points about classes vs objects

Answer (score -1):

Think of Classes as global objects.