# Ruby's Classes and Objects

Tags: ruby

I've been reading a lot about ruby classes vs objects and I came to this conclusion

There is a concept called "class" and we have the following classes:

```
BasicObject
```

which is the superclass of

```
Object
```

which is the superclass of

```
Module
```

which is the superclass of

```
Class
```

so:

1. the "class" `Class` is a subclass of "class" `Object`
2. Because all of the above "Class, Module, Object, Basic Object" are instances of "class" the concept. `Instance_of? Class` will
   return true for all them
3. On the other hand `(Object.new).instance_of? Class` will return false, because `(Object.new)` is an instance of "class" `Object`

questions:

- `Class.is_a? Object` is true because `Class` is a subclass of `Object` but `Object.is_a? Class` returns true as well, is that because Class here refers to the bigger class concept? If so why? isn't that confusing? How would I know which class is which?

Comment: What do you mean “bigger class concept”?

Comment: like "Class" that is a subclass of "Object" vs "class" where everything is a class including "Object" ... does that makes sense?

Comment: There is only one Class. Does [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4967556/211563) seem like it answers yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several things wrong.

- (2.) The reason `Class`, `Module`, `Object`, and `Basic Object` are instances of `Class` is not because `Class < Module < Object < BasicObject`. It has nothing to do with it.
- (3.) `(Object.new).instance_of? Class` returns `false` not because `Object.new` is an instance of `Object`. It is because it is not an instance of `Class`.
- `Class.is_a? Object` is `true` not because [the mentioned] `Class` is a subclass of `Object`. It is because (the mentioned) `Class` is an instance of `Class` (which is not mentioned), which is a subclass of `Object`.

The answer to the question is: `Object.is_a? Class` returns `true` because `Object` is an instance of `Class`.

If you want to know the class of an instance, use `instance_of?` or `class` methods.

```
3.is_a?(Object) # => false
3.is_a?(Fixnum) # => true
3.class # => Fixnum
```

Answer (score -1):

What's really going in is that Ruby is cheating. Matz wanted to copy the elegance of smalltalk when he designed Ruby, namely the rule

> Everything is an object.

To put that more technically

> Everything is an instance of the `Object` class or one of its subclasses.

However, as you've seen, that simple rule leads to some confusing situations. How does all of that craziness work? Like I said, it cheats. The Ruby interpreter is hard coded to lie about certain relationships so that the golden rule of "everything is an object" *looks* like it's unbroken. Here it is straight from the source:

```
void Init_class_hierarchy(void)
{
    /* the normal hierarchy we know and love */
    rb_cBasicObject = boot_defclass("BasicObject", 0);
    rb_cObject = boot_defclass("Object", rb_cBasicObject);
    rb_cModule = boot_defclass("Module", rb_cObject);
    rb_cClass =  boot_defclass("Class",  rb_cModule);

    /* sneaky stuff to force consistent behavior!!! */
    rb_const_set(rb_cObject, rb_intern_const("BasicObject"), rb_cBasicObject);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cClass, rb_cClass);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cModule, rb_cClass);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cObject, rb_cClass);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cBasicObject, rb_cClass);
}
```

And there are a lot more cases in the source code where built in classes need special treatment in order to give the "least surprising" result. Basically when it comes down to abstract internal stuff like this, don't worry about it. Just assume that things will behave as expected.

Comment: Downvoted because you're using a lot of ridiculous value judgments about a programming language. Please consider editing out words like "cheating" or "lying" and stick to tone-neutral explanations of the language mechanics. Thank you.

Comment: Uh... what? I have nothing but love for the Ruby language. The truth of the matter is that its wonderfully elegant object model is only achieved using hacks to get around the limitations of its actual implementation. Feel free to edit my answer if you can think of a better way to describe the interpreter forcing results to give the appearance of consistency.