# Class hierarchy in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've just got deeper in Ruby hierarchy to understand it. For example,

```
class Test
end

t = Test.new
```

So, if I want to get class of t I need to get 'class' property:

```
t.class # 'Test'
```

If I want to get parent of Test class I should use 'superclass' method:

```
t.class.superclass # BasicObject
```

But also Test is an instance of Class class. So, if I execute the following thing:

```
t.class.class # Class
```

So, I don't understand the difference between 'superclass' and 'class.class'; why aren't Class superclass for Test? What does it mean? Doest Test inherit methods of Class or BasicObject or both ones? Please, explain this thigns to me. I came from Java and I didn't hear about this features before. Thanks.

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967556/ruby-craziness-class-vs-object/4967663#4967663 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525053/ruby-metaclass-confusion/10526013#10526013 relevant

Comment: Also for me t.class.superclass is Object, not BasicObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by default, implicit superclass of the class you define is `Object`, not `BasicObject`. 
Now, `Test.superclass` methods returns class that `Test` directly inherits from. While `Test.class` returns class that `Test` is instance of. Remember that classes in Ruby are also objects, all objects in Ruby belongs to some class.

Answer (score 1):

Every object responds to `class`. It says what class the object is an *instance* of.

Only classes respond to `superclass`. It says what class the class is a *subclass* of.

```
Foo = Class.new # class Foo; end
foo = Foo.new

Foo.class # Class
foo.class # Foo

Bar = Class.new(Foo) # class Bar < Foo; end
Bar.class # Class
Bar.superclass # Foo
```

All classes are *instances* of Class. Ruby *does not allow* subclasses of Class.

Answer (score 0):

All objects are descendents of class Object. Class is object too and it is an instance of Object, which can seem a little weird.

```
    class Test
    end

    Test.class # => Class
    Test.superclass # => Object
    Object.class # => Class
    Class.superclass # => Module
    Module.class # => Class
    Module.superclass # => Object
    Object.superclass # => BasicObject
```

All descendents of class Object inherit quite a lot of methods like clone, dup, freeze and many many other methods. On the other hand BasicObject will provide you almost no methods - it doesn't even provide you methods: methods and public_methods.