# How can ruby Object be a subclass of Object?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

```
2.3.3 :001 > Object.class #=> Class
2.3.3 :002 > Class.ancestors #=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

I just can't wrap my head around this concept.

What I imagine is something like shown below

```
class Object < Class
  ...
end

class Class < Module
  ...
end

class Module < Object
  ...
end
```

This might seem stupid, am I missing something? I can't seem to find any related answers.

Comment: You must read [Ruby craziness: Class vs Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4967556/10522579)

Comment: "This might seem stupid, am I missing something?" – You are missing that you are wrong. `Object` is not a subclass of `Class`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yeah I know, I was trying to make sense of what I read [here](https://medium.com/@ensallee/ruby-inheritance-and-object-hierarchy-e0f908630fc7) by imagining that silly scenario

Comment: That article makes no sense. It is exactly the same as claiming "`'Hello'` is an instance of `String`. `String` is a subclass of `Object`. Therefore, `'Hello'` is a subclass of `Object`." In this case, it is much more obvious that this is wrong, since `'Hello'` isn't even a class *at all*, and therefore *cannot possibly be* a "subclass" of something. The exact same thing is true for `Object`, except that `Object` also happens to be a class, which confuses the matter slightly, if you're not careful about whether you are currently talking about `Object` as an object or `Object` as a class.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` class is NOT a subclass of `Class`, obviously. In fact, `Object` is a subclass of `BasicObject` and a default superclass for other classes:

```
Object.superclass
# => BasicObject

class A
end

A.superclass
# => Object
```

You've mistaken object's `class` (which indicates of what class is the given object, `Object` is a class, so this method indicates properly) with inheritance, I guess.

Comment: Object < BasicObject right? Why then Object.class #=> Class ?

Comment: Because `Object` is class, you can instantize it with `Object.new` etc. `Kernel` is a module mixed into an `Object` class.

Comment: @vishnuprasanth: The class of a string is `String`. Does that surprise you? The class of an integer is `Integer`. Does that surprise you? Then, it shouldn't surprise you that the class of a class is `Class`, no?

Comment: @JörgWMittag What surprises me is Object.class #=> Class.

Comment: @vishnuprasanth: Because `Object` is a class, and therefore its class is `Class`, in *exactly the same way* that `'Hello'` is a string, and therefore its class is `String` and not `'Hello'`. Now, `Object` *also* happens to be an object, in *exactly the same way* that `'Hello'` also happens to be an object, which is why both `Class` and `String` ultimately inherit from `Object`.